# Github action GAE deployment with "did not find any jar files with a Main-Class manifest entry"

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, continuous-deployment

We are using google app engine for deploying our server. And we are using the github action for the continuous deployment to work. Deploying it manually works and remotely the authentication step works as well, however, it says "did not find any jar files with a Main-Class manifest entry"
I am quite new at github actions and google app engine
[log of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvODK.png)

Adding an entrypoint worked for the action but the server got broken and returns a 500. This is probably because when running our spring boot app with `mvn install`, it gives us errors, but when we run, `mvn spring-boot:run` there is no bug.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvzVl.png)
This is the code block

```
package com.routezero.tracking.services.carbon;

import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

@Service
public class DBInitialiser {
    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        try {
            FileInputStream serviceAccount =
                    new FileInputStream("./travelcarbontracking-firebase.json");

            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                    .setDatabaseUrl(".....")
                    .build();

            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Just an update, the problem was not with maven but with app.yaml. The way i deployed it had an entry point defined as ```entrypoint: java -Xmx64m -jar blahblah.jar``` causing the autodeployment working but the code itself breaks